# MapInfo displays a JP2 raster weirdly - why?

Tags: raster, mapinfo, jpeg-2000

We have some JP2 files created with FME 2013. They work just fine in ArcGIS, MapModeller and QGIS. But when viewing it in MapInfo (11.5) we get what looks rather like a 60's drug trip.

[image]

Zooming in all the way doesn't resolve the issue, so its not just with the pyramids.

[image]

Any thoughts? I'm going to try re-generating the bad ones.

Note: Not all of them are "bad" - but most are.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out its because there were `.j2i` files in the directory from the previous versions of the rasters. I guess these are files created by MapInfo at runtime that contain an index of sorts which is used to decompress them.

Deleting the .j2i files resolved the issue.